# Handling Internet Connection Error when sharing on facebook from android

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm using facebook sdk to share content from android app. I'm using Facebook ShareButton widget. 
If the internet connection is ON, thing goes well. But, if there is no connection, 
a dialog is showing that,
"Unfortunately Facebook has stopped"
As ShareButton works automatically, no onclick listener is needed to provide, I cannot handle the click to check internet connection.
So, How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for how to checking the internet connection you have to check the Android [DOC](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html).

here is the code you need:

```
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    if(isConnected){
       //some code 
    }
```